# null pointer exception just after declaring variable

Tags: java, variables, nullpointerexception

I have a piece of code, I declare the variable i in a for loop, right after that I tried to print i and it gives me a null pointer exception. I really can't figure why, I just declared the variable..

```
 public void normalization(){
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVariables; i++){
            out.print(i);
            double min = unitRow.getMin(i);
            double max = unitRow.getMax(i);

            for(int j = 0; j < numberOfRecords; j++){
                double normalizedValue = normalizeValue(unitRow.unitArray[j].numberRow.numberArray[i],min,max);
                unitRow.unitArray[j].numberRow.update(i, normalizedValue);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Means that `out` is null. Did you mean `System.out` ?

Comment: You should probably say *what's* null. Obviously `i` isn't null.

Comment: I declared a printStream out earlier in the program, it works in other methodes

Comment: Just try to debug and see for yourself. Maybe it has something to do with `out`'s scope ? One thing is certain, `i` is not involved.

Comment: @tortilla Without any context it's impossible to say anything other than you didn't declare it how you think you did, or you're calling it before you've set it, or... etc. It has zero to do with `i`, and everything to do with `out`.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace (or at least a line number where the error occurs)? Are you sure the error is with `out.print(i)` and not somewhere else? `unitRow.unitArray[j].numberRow.numberArray[i]` looks suspect.

Comment: (Correct; I've been assuming OP didn't see the NPE  until the `out.println(i)`, but obviously that's a bad assumption.)

Comment: It said an error on the line:  out.print(i); 
However, I see my stupid mistake now, I said out.close(); in a methode just before this one, so the printStream was closed..
Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: @tortilla Closing it wouldn't make it null, though: this is why it's really important to make your questions complete and self-contained. You should have included the stack trace, and more context.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize `out`?   `System.out.print()` is the normal command...it may be getting confused by the simple `out`.

Comment: far far ago in a place long long away I used to remember the command to let you use only out.print instead of the full command.  But it IS possible

Comment: I don't remember anything about it at all.  It was probably something simple and stupid, but for the life of me, I cant remember.

I rarely use System.out.println() anymore these days.  I wrote my own debug function which prepends tags for me and redirects the output to any provided output stream.

Comment: yep.  and once I get the project stable, I will spend the time as the sole developer to implement a better logging framework.  In the meantime, however, my method does what it needs to do.

Comment: I'm saying there already *are* logging frameworks, that's all--as a sole developer aiming to reuse the work of others should be a priority, at least IMO.

Comment: When I started the project, I wasn't aware of any logging frameworks (project started several years ago, when I was younger and less wise in the ways of the forc- I mean java).  In general, though, I agree that such frameworks are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The line out.print(i) should be System.out.println(i);

Comment: Unless it's a static import, or some other output stream.

Answer (score 0):

what is `out` ??

You should assign it like `PrintStream out = System.out;`

or simply use `System.out.print(i);`

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVariables; i++){
            System.out.print(i);
            double min = unitRow.getMin(i);
            double max = unitRow.getMax(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print `i` and that time you are getting `NullPointerException`.
`NullPointerException` occurs when you are calling a method on a reference variable which does not refer to any object. So in your case, obviously the `out` variable is `null`.

Please assign an object to it.

You can assign a printWriter by using

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.in);
```

or if you simply want to print on system using
    System.out.println();

Answer (score 0):

If its just 'i' that you want to print then use System.out.print(i). And it does not give null exception.